# How to create a reusable RecyclerView using "Composition over Inheritance"?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-custom-view

One of my coworkers created an inherit from a RecyclerView and added the logic to create its adapter, defined custom list item attributes, and layout manager inside it.

This is an example of his idea:

```
class CustomRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        loadCustomAttributes()
        setDefaultAdapter()
        setDefaultLayoutManager()
    }

    private fun loadCustomAttributes() {
        // Load custom attributes: item background, for example.
    }

    private fun setDefaultAdapter() {
        // Define specific Custom Adapter.
    }

    private fun setDefaultLayoutManager() {
        // Define specific Layout Manager.
    }

    fun setData(data: List) {
        // Set data and notify dataset changed.
    }

    private class CustomAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        // Specific Adapter.
    }

    private class ViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        // Specific View Holder.
    }

}
```

I understand his reasons, and it's very reasonable: he wants to plug a View on the XML and just reuse it, without defining the adapter or anything else on the Activity or Fragment; he will just set the data with the method "setData".

But on the other way, I feel that this class is inheriting a RecyclerView just to breaking the design of the RecyclerView and giving too many responsibilities to it. My pain points are:

1. A RecyclerView shouldn't decide an item attribute (item background colour, for example);
2. A RecyclerView shouldn’t know about his LayoutManager;
3. A RecyclerView shouldn't have methods to update the data on the adapter;
4. A RecyclerView shouldn’t create an instance of his Adapter.
5. This is an "inheritance over composition" approach.

I tried to find information about it on the internet, but I didn't find anything about good practices when inheriting from a ListView/RecyclerView.

Another idea would be to wrap it inside another layout (ViewGroup or FrameLayout) to encapsulate it. But this would create an unnecessary nested layout, and it will be complicated to test using Espresso (because now the list is private and shouldn't be exposed).

**My question is:** how to create a reusable RecyclerView using "Composition over Inheritance"?

Comment: I mean, if you look at it that way, every Fragment (and maybe even Activity) you write already has the same "inheritance over composition" problem.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce do you think so? For me, the difference is that when you inherit a RecyclerView and set a default Adapter internally, you still have the "setAdapter" method and all other specific RecyclerView methods that are not supported by your class, and your code depends on this Adapter to work, for example. You keep methods exposed that could "break" your implementation. On the other way, a Fragment (and Activity) is only exposing Android Framework related APIs like Lifecycle. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope, didn't think of it that way. What you can do instead is use this custom RecyclerView implementation internally but otherwise wrap it in a FrameLayout that exposes a given API of it.

Comment: Setting the adapter and layout manager to the RecyclerView is already composition.